# How to Change DNS Servers Programmatically in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, dns

I want to change DNS servers programmatically. I don't want to build a DNS server, I just want to change the primary and secondary dns servers automatically. This work needs to be done in Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call a command line tool to do it for you with os.system.

```
import os
os.system('netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.200')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
# The first thing you need to import os and identify is the name of the network interface you want to modify.
# You can find the names of all network interfaces by running the following command:
os.system('netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces')
# for me its "Wi-Fi"
# For the primary DNS server run:
os.system('netsh interface ip set dns name="Wi-Fi" static 185.37.37.37')
# For the secondary DNS server run:
os.system('netsh interface ip add dns name="Wi-Fi"  185.37.39.39 index=2')
# whene you'r done with the DNS server run :
os.system('netsh interface ip set dnsservers name="Wi-Fi" source=dhcp')
#keep in mind  that you need administrator privilege
```