# Python OpenSSL Specify DNS Server

Tags: python, dns, pyopenssl

Has anyone found a way to specify a DNS server for OpenSSL connections on a Linux OS?  We have internal and external DNS servers and I am building a monitor for SSL certificate usage.  I need the ability to specify a DNS server to be used on hostname connections.  It works just fine against the internal DNS, but I am having difficulty finding a way to tie in a DNS server.  I am fairly new to changing networks through Python and am not sure where to begin.  Is it possible to do this through the dns.resolver module's nameservers function?

This looks like a viable solution for Windows, but I am hoping to find something similar for Linux.
[How to Change DNS Servers Programmatically in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415771/how-to-change-dns-servers-programmatically-in-windows)

Below is my code that works against the default DNS host.

```py
def readCerts(self,host,port,cast):
    """readCerts prompts terminal for username.
    Attributes:
        host: Host or IP of SSL connection
        port: Port of SSL connection
        cast: Format of returned results (JSON currently only structure supported)
    Response:
        Returns certificate attributes in specified format
    """
    sslContext = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
    apiSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sslConnection = SSL.Connection(sslContext,apiSocket)

    try:
        sslConnection.connect((host,port))
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    else:
        #Block the socket 
        sslConnection.setblocking(1)
        #Set the hostname field for servers that support SNI.  Format must be in bytestring.
        sslConnection.set_tlsext_host_name(host.encode('utf-8'))

        try:
            sslConnection.do_handshake()
        except:
            pass
        else:
            #print "handshake succeeded"
            sslConnection.close()
            if cast.upper()=='JSON':
                attributes = self._FormatJSON(sslConnection.get_peer_cert_chain())        
                return attributes
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/762738 (not a python code though)

Comment: Just provide an IP address for the "SSL" connection, no need to mess with local DNS configuration for that. You can use Python dnspython module to do DNS queries (to whatever nameserver you want) and grab the IP addresses you need.

Comment: Thank you Patrick.  I forgot to follow up.  This is exactly what I did.  connect() on the IP and passing hostname as SNI.